# How do I disable the prompt on suspend?

Tags: xubuntu

When ever I go to `suspend` I get a prompt

> Do you want to suspend to RAM?
>   Suspending computer in 30 seconds.

I do want that prompt, it's new to Xubuntu 12.10. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I use ubuntu tweak to supress any requests from the system like that.

[Ubuntu Tweak Download](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/)

Comment: I'd rather just know how to suppress this one annoying request. It's new to 12.10.